# Split String into array based on every second occurrence

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm sure this is a fairly easy one but my java is very rusty.

I have an example string

> aaa\n123\nbbb\n124\ncccdef\n125\ndefg\n126

what I need to do is split the string into sets based on every second occurrence of \n which would result in an array of:

> aaa\n123
>
> bbb\n124
>
> cccdef\n125
>
> defg\n126

How can I achieve this?

Comment: From the example, can you ensure that there are always characters and numbers?

Comment: if your end of the row char were something else than \n for exaple like \t then you could just use this simple line: `String[] lines = exampleString.split("\t");`

Comment: I recommend using regular expressions for this. I don't know which one is the right regex though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another code for you. It solves your problem. Tested and verified.

```
        String temp = "aaa\n123\nbbb\n124\ncccdef\n125\ndefg\n126";
        String parts[] = temp.split("\n");
        ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i =i+2) {
            listItems.add(parts[i]+"\\n"+parts[i+1]);

        }
             /*Below loop is just to verify if your list contains correct items, Printing logs*/
        for (int i = 0; i < listItems.size(); i++) {

            Log.d("TEMP","item = "+ listItems.get(i));
        }
```

P.S:- Just confirm that you added NULL check wherever required. :) Happy Coding.

Comment: +1 For your verified answer, I think others were in hurry to answer rather then checking their own code..

Comment: @CRUSADER Thanks for appreciation. 
Cghmauritius > Your welcome, Enjoy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

one attempt could be a regex.
or you split it on every occurance and build the pairs on your own

Answer (score 0):

```
String example; //your string
String c = "\\n"; //I assume your delimiter is actually the "\n" string not the newline

String[] pieces = example.split(c);
ArrayList<String> final_list = new ArrayList<String>;

bool add = false;
String mem;

for (String s : pieces) {
    if (add) {
        final_list.add(mem+c+s);
    } else {
        mem = s;
    }
    add = !add;
}
```

Comment: "\\n" cannot be a char. It need to b String.. Have you check your code before posting..

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
    String input = "aaa\n123\nbbb\n124\ncccdef\n125\ndefg\n126";
    String[] splitted = input.split("\n");
    String[] finalArray = new String[splitted.length / 2];
    int idx =0;

    for(int i=0; i<splitted.length; i=i+2) {
        finalArray[idx] = finalArray[i] + finalArray [i+1];
        idx++;
    }
```

Comment: you may need to correct the loop conditions. ;)

"  for(int i=0; i<splitted.length-1; i=+2) { "

Answer (score 0):

```
String data = "aaa\n123\nbbb\n124\ncccdef\n125\ndefg\n126";

        String[] splitData = data.split("\n");
        List<String> finalData = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
            temp.append(splitData[i]);
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                finalData.add(temp.toString());
                temp = new StringBuilder();
            } else {
                temp.append("\n");
            }
        }
```